# Qt5: lineEdit Не учитывается значение с запятой

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Есть некоторая форма на которой есть `lineEdit`.
[image: скриншот окна]

Для этого поля задан валидатор `QDoubleValidator(0, 100000, 4)`
Проблема такая: при вводе в поле вещественного значения(а оно представляется в виде 1234,1234 т.е. с запятой) данное значение чудным образом обращается в ноль. Целые же обрабатываются корректно. Я написал суррогатный пример для демонстрации этой аномалии:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QValidator>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->lineEdit->setValidator(new QDoubleValidator(0, 100000, 4));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    double _sPrice;
    _sPrice = ui->label->text().toDouble();
    //label располагается над LineEdit'oм
    _sPrice += ui->lineEdit->text().toDouble();

    ui->label->setText(QString::number(_sPrice));
}
```

Вопрос №1: В чём может быть дело? Как поправить?
Вопрос №2: В чём смысл top значения у QDoubleValidator? Как я понял, он по QValidator::Acceptable не пропускает значения вне диапазона [bottom, top];

Изображения с наглядным представлением аномалии:
[image: К нулю добавляем какое-либо целочисленное значение, всё работает корректно]
[image: Теперь к 124 пытаемся добавить 99,99 и теперь ничего не происходит]

Comment: советую вместо обрывков из контекста кода, понятного только вам, создать простой компилируемый пример, воспроизводящий проблему.

Comment: Да. Переделано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была из-за запятой. Заменив её точкой, строка преобразовывается в `double`.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{       
    double _sPrice;
    _sPrice = ui->label->text().toDouble();
    QString _strLineEditPrice = ui->lineEdit->text().replace(',', '.');
    _sPrice += _strLineEditPrice.toDouble();
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(_sPrice, 'g', 10));
}
```

Comment: Ам... тогда почему `QDoubleValidator` точку не пропускают, а вместо оной пропускают запятую?

Comment: Возможно есть какие-то спецфлаги для этого класса, гляньте доку